# Hide Radio Button but Show Label?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I'm tryng to hide radio button while showing label image.

```
<span id="js" class='info'>
  <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" size="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="js(this.value, this.size);" /><img src="something.jpg"/></label>
  <br />No:
  <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" size="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="js(this.value, this.size);" /><img src="something.jpg"/></label>
 </span>
```

I know this requires jquery to be linked with my span's id "js" but don't know the javascript code for it. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

```
$('#js input[type=radio]').hide()
```

Comment: Only if he has jQuery on the site

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$("#js input[type=radio]").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Following worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
       $("label input:radio").wrap('<label></label>').parent().hide();
</script>
```

Comment: This should not be an answer, but a comment to the answer. Also, you should accept the correct answer by clicking the green check mark.